# how to configure a react app for production

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I want to deploy my react app to production (using heroku). When the app is deployed, React dev tools indicates that my app is running in development mode

I pushed the application to heroku : https://lesamisdhubert.herokuapp.com/

I tried to set an environment variable :
`heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production`

however, when I console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV), It returns development

I also tried `npm run build` before pushing to production but it hasn't worked

here are my scripts in the package.json file :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

however `console.log('node env --->', process.env.NODE_ENV);` returns 'development'

Does anybody knows how I can set my react app into production mode ? Is this a problem with npm run build ?
Thanks a lot, I really don't understand where this can come from ...

Comment: Did you install create-react-app buildpack on heroku?

Comment: I think I didn't : I did a ```npm run build``` 
I followed the steps in the Usage section of this article : https://github.com/zhukmj/create-react-app-buildpack#user-content-create-the-heroku-app

Answer (score 1):

I replaced in package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  }
```

I also created a new heroku app and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

When configuring enviroment vars in heroku you have to append REACT_APP_VARIABLENAME and then set its value otherwise you can't have access to the env variable.

take a look at: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#compile-time-configuration

you can do this in the heroku client

---

Comment: Hi !
I already used ```heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production```, that's the same isn't it ?

Comment: Hello, no that is not, please read the article that i posted there, in order to have access to enviroment variables in react with Heroku you have to set them up as REACT_APP_NAMEOFVARIABLE

Comment: Okay thanks ! I am not quite sure but I changed my scripts in the package.json file and it seems to work.
Thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: Not a problem, try to be a little more specific about what you did and post it in your answer so if anyone has the same problem they can take a look at your solution. Glad to try to help!