# How can I conditionally check if React app is in 'production' or 'dev' in a Heroku environment?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, create-react-app

**Here is the code:**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./keys_prod');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./keys_dev');
}
```

keys_prod ***IS*** on the server

keys_dev is only on my local machine

**Here is the problem:**

when the app starts up on Heroku I get the following:

```
ERROR in ./src/environment/keys.js 8:2-40
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './keys_dev' in '/app/src/environment'
```

**Heroku Config vars**

I seem to remember reading somewhere, a long time ago that environment variables in Heroku for a React app needed to be prefixed with `REACT_APP` in order for the React app to pick them up... but that doesn't seem to be the case now.

I have the following set in the Heroku config vars:

[image]

**package.json**

my package.json scripts section

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
```

saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327376/how-to-configure-a-react-app-for-production) but I am on heroku 22 - so that won't work

**Try 1**

It was suggested to set `NODE_ENV` to production...

[image]

**Try 1 - Result**

```
ERROR in ./src/environment/keys.js 8:2-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './keys_dev' in '/app/src/environment'
```

Comment: "environment variables in Heroku for a React app needed to be prefixed with `REACT_APP` in order for the React app to pick them up"—this has nothing to do with Heroku, it's just how front-end applications work. They run in the user's browser, not on the server. They have no access to the server's environment. [But environment variables prefixed with `REACT_APP_` get baked in at compile time](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/). (Though `NODE_ENV` is special: it _doesn't_ need a prefix.)

Answer (score -1):

You're setting `REACT_APP_NODE_ENV`, but not `NODE_ENV`. Set `NODE_ENV` to production.

Comment: tried that... did NOT work (edited question as Try1 )

Comment: @MrLister Then do some debugging. Dump the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` to your logs.

Comment: @MrLister, did you rebuild your application after setting `NODE_ENV`? I suspect not.

Answer (score -1):

THIS works

```
if (process.env.REACT_APP_NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./keys_prod');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./keys_dev');
}
```

Comment: This isn't the right solution: [`NODE_ENV` is the only variable that _doesn't_ need to be prefixed with `REACT_APP_`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/). And it [should be set to `production` by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#runtime-behavior).

Comment: Are you suggesting this an answer, or is it meant to be a comment adding clarification to the question? If it's a comment, please delete it and edit it into your question. As an answer it is _at best_ a poor work around.